# SharePoint - Folder navigation click does not work correctly when using Filter By option. Fix with column formatting JSON?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have large document library that has a lot of nested folders/content. My users need to use the "Filter By" option on the column header to filter to the folder they are looking to drill into.

However, when they find the folder and click into the folder, it says no items were found. Sharepoint seems to be sending them into that folder, then applying another "Filter By". To the user, this appears like they have no documents.

Here is the sequence:

**Step 1)**

User applies the filter:

[image]

**Step 2)**

User clicks on the link to that folder (name column or double click the row). They are taken to a path like this.

[image]

**Step 3)**

In order to get to the contents of the folder they are navigating to, They have to click one level above.

[image]

Step 4) User clicks on the previous level "SharepointTestMigration" and is taken to the correct place.

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this? This behavior seems odd to me. I am hoping with some of the column-based JSON formatting, there is an option to change the behavior of that click action.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is a bug from Microsoft's end. It should not add **SharePointTestMigration** two times in breadcrumb navigation at the top.

Report this behavior to Microsoft directly using - [Get M365 support - online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Also, there is no way to manage the breadcrumb navigation behavior using SharePoint JSON formatting.